# Can I send emails from parent domain instead of subdomain used by SAP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sap, sender-authentication-package

We have setup our SAP in MC as `mailer.company.com`, therefor all our sender emails currently are like `support@mailer.company.com`. Could we add custom sender address like `support@company.com` and have the reply-to address as default so they continue to use RMM?

If so, are there any other considerations doing this? I was under the impression any addresses that arent from the SAP domain have lower deliverability.

Comment: Your RMM I believe is required to use the SAP attached to your account. I am not sure that it is possible via a custom domain.  The deliverability using non-SAP domains would not be lowered per se. It just would be more in your hands to correctly monitor and maintain the domain (updates on spf,dkim, etc. etc.) compared to the SAP where SFMC handles this.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the deliverability notes you made? If its not affected whats to stop people from emailing customers from other domains (aside from verification).

Comment: There is nothing other than domain verification and technical responsibility that stop people from emailing customers from other domains in SFMC. The main draw of SAP is that the IP and domain inside of it are managed, maintained and prepared by SFMC and not reliant on your own IT team. This also allows Support, etc. to better be able to troubleshoot your issues. Any extra Deliverability effects would be only caused by: authentication issues (SPF,DKIM,DMARC), DNS issues with setup and maintenance, etc.  Basically all the technical stuff behind the scenes.